# Is there a module for comments and likes on Drupal 7 like a social media

Tags: module, drupal-7, social-networking

There is a site which is hosted on drupal. The site also has a android mobile app for which i am creating a social network. I want to know if there is any module which would reduce the load on the RDS and make use of caching mechanism of drupal.

Comment: it doesn't look like your question relates to `android`

Comment: What is RDS? Is it related to Drupal? It is not clear.